# how can I change a php include without reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I've been trying to learn most of this as I go so as with previous questions I've posed some of this may seem simplistic or blatantly over my head - with that said I learn best through peer explanation/example/advice so thanks in advance.

I have used what I've learned here so far to build the basic structure of my personal website. The concept is an right aligned accordion menu that remains from page to page while the content and backgrounds in the area to the left will change based on the menu selection - fundamentally like frames or iframes used to look.

THE PROBLEM:
I have some js knowledge and I know that I can cycle some of the content out via getElementById but as these will be in a gallery I didn't want to drag my speed down by loading 54+ images in the background. I also know that I can just make the thumbnails in the sidebar  link with php and just load the page entirely but as I don't want the menu to change I've been trying to figure out the best method to go about this. So far I've heard mention of PHP, JQuery and AJAX (which I know by name but is new to me). Below is an example of the code and what I want to do:

```
<body>
<div id="all">
  <div id="live-area">

    <?php include("blog.php") ?>

  </div>
  <div id="side-bar-area">
    <div id="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="nestedAccordion">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>
      <div>
        <h3>Branding</h3>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li class="thumbs">
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example1.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example2.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example3.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example4.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example5.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example6.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example7.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example8.jpg"/></a>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example9.jpg"/></a>
        </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>Blog</h2>
        <div>
          <ul style="margin:0px;">
            <li>entry 1</li>
            <li>entry 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>About</h2>
        <div>
          <ul style="margin:0px;">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Resume</li>
            <li>Accolades</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Based on the above, what I want is that whenever any of the items in the menu such as `<a href="#"><img src="images/thumbs/example1.jpg"/></a>` are selected it will change the content of `<?php include("blog.php") ?>` without reloading the page.

Firstly, is this doable? And secondly, does anyone have advice for a novice in terms of this - either basic tutorials or a how-to for the layman?

Comment: Do you mean, that if you select an image, it would have to load some content associated with it?

Comment: Yeah, AJAX and jQuery would be a good place to start on image click you can make an AJAX call that returns a different PHP page and changes what is in the "live-area"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you added `jquery` to your tags, you could use AJAX to perform a server side request and load the new content and replace the existing one.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.org/other-page.php',
    dataType: 'html'
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Assuming the request returns HTML, replace content
    $('#live-area').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

In `html`,

```
<div id="live-area">
    <?php include("blog.php") ?>
</div>
<li class="thumbs">
    <a href="#" data-page="page1.php"><img src="images/thumbs/example1.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#" data-page="page2.php"><img src="images/thumbs/example2.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#" data-page="page3.php"><img src="images/thumbs/example3.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="#" data-page="page4.php"><img src="images/thumbs/example4.jpg"/></a>
</li>
```

In `script`,

```
<script>
$('.thumbs a').click(function(){
    var page    =   $( this ).attr('data-page');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:page,
        success: function(response){
            $('#live-area').html(response);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```